# find out why my web server becomes unavailable

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

I have a python web server (django)

It talks to other services such as elasticsearch

I notice when elasticsearch goes down, the web server soon (after a few minutes) stops responding to client requests.

I use https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py and it implements timeout and don't think it's blocking.

My hunch is that requests piles up during the timeout period and server becomes unavailable but it's a just guess.

What's the reason for the server not being able to handle requests in such a scenario and how do I fix it?

I have `nginx - uwsgi - django` on unix (amazon ecs) setup if that makes difference

Comment: Hard to judge because you didn't include any user code, but it sounds to me like some suppressed exceptions, ie elasticsearch query wrapped in try...except which somehow breaks the application?

Comment: Enable the error logs in elasticsearch and see if it is complaining about anything in there? Check your indicies also in index management if you have any red ones.